# interaction between the oracle smart contract and the oracle service

Tags: oracle, events, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js

I want to use this code to recover the temperature and return the result to the smart contract

```
contract CMCOracle {
    // Contract owner   address public owner;
    // BTC Marketcap Storage   uint public btcMarketCap;
    // Callback function   event CallbackGetBTCCap();

    function CMCOracle() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function updateWe() public {
        // Calls the callback function
        CallbackGetBTCCap();
    }

    function setBTCCap(uint cap) public {
        // If it isn't sent by a trusted oracle
        // a.k.a ourselves, ignore it
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        btcMarketCap = cap;
    }

    function getBTCCap() constant public returns (uint) {
        return btcMarketCap;
    }
}
```

```js
var fetch = require('fetch')
var OracleContract = require('./build/contracts/CMCOracle.json')
var contract = require('truffle-contract')

var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://localhost:8545'));

// Truffle abstraction to interact with our
// deployed contract
var oracleContract = contract(OracleContract);
oracleContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

// Dirty hack for web3@1.0.0 support for localhost testrpc
// see https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/issues/56#issuecomment-331084530
if (typeof oracleContract.currentProvider.sendAsync !== "function") {
    oracleContract.currentProvider.sendAsync = function() {
        return oracleContract.currentProvider.send.apply(
            oracleContract.currentProvider, arguments
        );
    };
 }

// Get accounts from web3 web3.eth.getAccounts((err, accounts) => {
oracleContract.deployed().then((oracleInstance) => {
    // Watch event and respond to event
    // With a callback function
    oracleInstance.CallbackGetBTCCap()
    .watch((err, event) => {
        // Fetch data
        // and update it into the contract
        fetch.fetchUrl('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/',(err, m, b)=> {
            const cmcJson = JSON.parse(b.toString());
            const btcMarketCap = parseInt(cmcJson.total_market_cap_usd);

            // Send data back contract on-chain
            oracleInstance.setBTCCap(btcMarketCap, {from: accounts[0]});
        })
    })
}).catch((err) => { console.log(err) });
```

but I can't understand how to change the code.

- How does the smart contract pass a city whose temperature I want to know to the oracle service?
- What API does the oracle service use to fetch the temperature from the external source?
- How should i change this code?

source: https://kndrck.co/posts/ethereum_oracles_a_simple_guide/

Answer (score 0):

1. A smart contract does not interact with the API but the Oracle itself. Normally, it should have been two different contracts like one of the contracts should be separated from the external world. Oracle contract is the API for blockchain, which is basically residing in the blockchain. You can reach out to the contract by means of contract wrapper libraries (web3j, ethereumj)
2. The contract wrapper will fetch the data from API as JSON. And then the application will convert the data into primitive data that has been defined in the Solidity language. Once it is done, data will send via emit-event functions continuously to the blockchain as long as the application fetched data from the API. In the end, you will have a deterministic database source so that you can copy this source and transfer another place as it is.
3. For instance, you may change the API endpoint called `"https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/"` with `"api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"` and data structures (link: https://openweathermap.org/current).